# Syntax error and compile-time errors the same thing?

Tags: compiler-errors, runtime-error

Syntax error and compile-time errors same thing? and what about run time errors

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to Java,

Syntax error are the ones that violates grammar rule of any programming language. So, When the source code is compiled (I-e, converted into bytecode version of the program; which is a computer understandable language), then these errors are visible after compilation. Therefore we can say that compile-time or compilation errors can be a Syntax error on the basis that they are visible after the file is compiled. And, run-time error are the ones that occurs when the actual program(executable file/bytecode version of file) is run/executed.

One thing we have to understand from here is that, the source file/source code is a compilation unit. It is not an executable file, To actually run the program, we need bytecode version of a program which is an executable file.

Additionally, Logical error is the one that has problems with your logic, in simple words it is a bug because it compiles and runs but does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error is an error in coding syntax. generally things like a misplaced '{' or '}' or ';' or one of many syntax related things.(EDIT: like: dofunction("somevalue); <- syntax error: missing '"')

compile time error is an error that occurs while the program is being compiled. many things can cause this. (edit: such as syntax errors. compiling is the processing of converting the human readable text code into machine language(1s and 0s) for execution)

run time errors are errors that happen while the program is actively running( aka: RUNtime. like trying to copy data from an array that is empty will throw a runtime error as it happened while the code was executing.)